# Evaluate excel concatenate formula only once

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am building a template/form in excel that will be used by different people on different computers to fill in some information and then send it by email to me.

When the template is being filled I need to assign an unique ID number to a field along with other info(kind of like a request ID). I am generating this unique ID by using

```
CONCATENATE("NER-";DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0;4294967295);8))
```

This formula serves me good for the task at hand.

My challenge is to evaluate this formula only one time in the template and then keep it the same when I open the file once it gets to me. Something along the lines of a time stamp. I have already looked into some methods but I cannot seem to get it to work.

I have tried making use of:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    With Target
        If .Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
        If Not Intersect(Range("A2:A10"), .Cells) Is Nothing Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            If IsEmpty(.Value) Then
                .Offset(0, 1).ClearContents
            Else
                With .Offset(0, 1)
                    .NumberFormat = "dd mmm yyyy hh:mm:ss"
                    .Value = Now
                End With
            End If
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

But I do not know how to integrate my concatenate function into the code. I am also not extremely sure if this will keep my unique value untouched when I open the template on my computer.

I would guess that a method that would limit my iterations in the entire sheet would also serve me good.

Comment: What about copy/pasting the values (meaning you then remove the formula) of the cell after evaluating it?

Comment: That would solve my issue indeed but seems more like an workaround rather than a real solution. I would like to keep this form as user friendly and clean as possible. Thank you for the idea though.

Comment: I am aware that random does not 100% guarantee unique, but as I said the formula of generating this is ok for my task at hand. I have a way of double-checking if I get to identical ID's.

Comment: That random stuff, there's a wide range, ok, but it can repeat from time to time. Can't you generate the ID yourself when you receive the e-mail by clicking a button on the sheet?

Comment: Does this ID need to be different from all other sheets you received before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could generate and store the ID right when the user first opens the workbook/template, placing this code in the ' `ThisWorbook` module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    'ID already set?
    If Sheet1.Range("A2").Value <> "" Then Exit Sub

    'Prevent that ID is generated on your machine
    If Environ$("Username") = "YOURUSERNAME" Then Exit Sub

    'Store ID
    Sheet1.Range("A2").Value = _
        "NER-" & [DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0,4294967295),8)]
End Sub
```

Comment: you're welcome! if it solved your problem, please mark it as the answer by clicking on the small checkmark! Thanks!